# Is this by design in MVC Model Binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

A simple scenario that I've never seen before, but a colleague has just hit - MVC3

> 1. Create an action method MyAction(int myProperty = 0)
> 2. Create a model that has a property MyProperty
> 3. Pass an instance of this model to a strongly typed view, but set the property to 10 in code (don't use the query string parameter!)
> 4. In the view, Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyProperty)

This should render 10 in the text box.

Now call the action method MyAction?myProperty=8

Shouldn't this still render 10 in the text box?

I see that I can override the property discovered by the expression and assume this is because they are the same name (`Query String` parameter and model property). Eveything is then in the `ViewData` but one overrides the other.

Is this by design?

Comment: This is about model binding actually, not Razor.

Comment: Are you @Html.TextBoxFor between a form using statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design - [ModelState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is the highest priority value-provider for model properties, higher than even model itself. Without query string parameter, ModelState does not contain value for `MyProperty`, so framework uses model value.

You can use `ModelState.Remove("MyProperty")` to ensure using model value

Comment: Thanks - Have never seen this before so I've learnt something new (again).

Comment: Or rename the url parameter (the action parameter).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code for `Html.TextBoxFor` you will see that if a value exists in `ModelState` then it will always use that value before any other.

```
string attemptedValue = (string)htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string));
tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", attemptedValue ?? ((useViewData) ? htmlHelper.EvalString(fullName, format) : valueParameter), isExplicitValue);
```

If the value is in ModelState, then it doesn't matter what you set in code.