# Route param and view model property with same name - unexpected behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

not sure if this is a bug, or I missed someting.

When I have a route param "bar" and in my view model a property with the same name "Bar", MVC gets confused and shows in the html helper unexpected results. Let's look a little closer.

(Code is free typed, so it may be not working, but I hope it is enough to get what I just stumbled about)

Let's start with the following controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
  ...
  [Route("my/route/{bar}")]
  public ActionResult Foo(string bar) {
    ...
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel() { Bar = "baz"; }

    return this.View(viewModel);
  }
  ...    
}
```

We pass the following view model to the view:

```
public class MyViewModel {
  ...
  public string Bar { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

In the view, wie have something like this:

```
...
@Html.LabelFor(l => l.Bar)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Bar)
...
```

When we call out action like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link", "Foo", "MyController", new { bar = "mystring" })
```

Expected result in EditorFor is `"baz"`, but this is *not* the case. Actually it is `"mystring"`. Even though `@Model.Bar` will print the expected result `"baz"`.

Is this desired behaviour, or a (known) bug? If not, where can I report this one?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the bug it is per design, that is how Model binder works in MVC:

> This is by design - ModelState is the highest priority value-provider
>   for model properties, higher than even model itself. Without query
>   string parameter, ModelState does not contain value for MyProperty, so
>   framework uses model value.

see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188737/is-this-by-design-in-mvc-model-binding) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18189040/1081079):